How to create a multi-line graph in R transposed (i.e., the other way) using ggplot2?
In most multi-line graphs, it graphs multiple entities of one column, however in my case I want to graph multiple columns of a single entity.
In more simple terms a multi-line graph might show life expectancy over time across different countries. What I want is a graph that shows the number of EMS calls in Pittsburgh overtime across different call reasons.
Most multi-line graphs look like this
However I want my graph to look like this (made in Excel):

The y-axis is number of calls and of course I graphed horizontal lines for convenience and simplicity.
Here are the current packages I'm using. I am open to using other packages though.
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

Here is my condensed data as a tibble (the full dataset has 30 different call reasons)
City_name <- (rep("PITTSBURGH", 6))
year_quarter <- c("2015Q1", "2015Q2", "2015Q3", "2015Q4", "2016Q1", "2016Q2")
ABDOMINAL_PAIN <- rep(10, 6)
ALLERGIES <- rep(12, 6)
ASSAULT <- rep(14, 6)
BACK_PAIN <- rep(16, 6)


df_0 <- tibble(City_name, year_quarter,ABDOMINAL_PAIN, ALLERGIES, ASSAULT, BACK_PAIN)

print(df_0)

# A tibble: 6 × 6
# City_name  year_quarter ABDOMINAL_PAIN ALLERGIES ASSAULT BACK_PAIN
# <chr>      <chr>                 <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 PITTSBURGH 2015Q1                   10        12      14        16
# 2 PITTSBURGH 2015Q2                   10        12      14        16
# 3 PITTSBURGH 2015Q3                   10        12      14        16
# 4 PITTSBURGH 2015Q4                   10        12      14        16
# 5 PITTSBURGH 2016Q1                   10        12      14        16
# 6 PITTSBURGH 2016Q2                   10        12      14        16
# > 

I also have a vector of the column names themselves
vec_col.names <- c("ABDOMINAL_PAIN", "ALLERGIES", "ASSAULT", "BACK_PAIN")

I am having trouble as most sources like this one that show the first way. I have not been able to find other resources and using the code provided by the source above.
north_big <- gapminder %>%
  filter(continent == "Americas", country %in% c("United States", "Canada", "Mexico"))

ggplot(north_big, aes(x = year, y = lifeExp, group = country)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = country), size = 2)


Thank you! It answers my question but partly; ggplot2 throws the following output in the console geom_line(): Each group consists of only one observation.  ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic? @tripleee

"Each group consists of only one observation": this is almsot certainly becase your "dates" aren't dates, they're character strings.  Convert your "dates" to datetimes, format the axis labels correctly and the problem should go away.  Exactly the same problem appears (and is solved) in the link provided in the duplicate above.

THe easiest way to do this is this:
library(tidyverse)

City_name <- rep("PITTSBURGH", 6)
year_quarter <- c("2015Q1", "2015Q2", "2015Q3", "2015Q4", "2016Q1", "2016Q2")
ABDOMINAL_PAIN <- rep(10, 6)
ALLERGIES <- rep(12, 6)
ASSAULT <- rep(14, 6)
BACK_PAIN <- rep(16, 6)

df_0 <- tibble(City_name, year_quarter, ABDOMINAL_PAIN, ALLERGIES, ASSAULT, BACK_PAIN)

df_long <- df_0 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = ABDOMINAL_PAIN:BACK_PAIN, names_to = "call_reason", values_to = "num_calls")

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = year_quarter, y = num_calls, color = call_reason, group = call_reason)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.2) +
  labs(title = "Number of EMS Calls in Pittsburgh",
       x = "Quarter",
       y = "Number of Calls",
       color = "Call Reason") +
  theme_minimal()


which returns

